# Is there any reason to use [: over @:?

Tags: j

`x ([: u v) y` expands to `u (x v y)`, but so does `x u@:v y`. `@:` strictly supersedes `[:` in [Special Codes](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/special.htm). Is there any reason to use `[:` over `@:`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some people prefer `([: f g)` to `f@:g` for readability, perhaps because it is more spread out, although `f @: g` accomplishes the same spacing without parentheses.

I am pretty sure that I have seen cases where it made a difference to the outcome, but I can't remember them now. Perhaps others will be able to come up with examples where they differ.

Comment: The parentheses in the first expression are superfluous; assigning that verb to a name, eg, will bind the same object with or without parentheses. The real difference is when `@:` requires parentheses. Effectively, we prefer `[: f g` to `f@:g` when the low binding power of conjunctions, as opposed to the higher binding power of the train rule in the grammar, requires us to actually write `f@:(g)`. This happens when, for example, `g` is a (n anonymous) train), or is modified by an adverb (eg `/`) or conjunction (eg `”0`) which we want to apply only to `g`, not `f@:g`.